# homebrew: how to revert to a previous version of gawk?

Tags: homebrew

I only see gawk version 5.0.0 here. I'd like to revert to a previous gawk version that were used to be in homebrew. I could check the git history and find out the appropriate version of the .rb file. But it is too tedious. Is there a much easier to revert to an older version of gawk?

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gawk.rb